# Difficult geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory

Given that A, B and C are the first three terms of a geometric sequence.

The product of $ABC=x-1$

Show that the $5^{th}$ term of the sequence is $7+5\sqrt{2}$.

My attempt: This question looks impossible, so I can't really do much here.

Because it is geometric we can say $\frac{B}{A}=\frac{C}{B}$

I got a hint:

One possible way to do this, is $\sqrt{x}-1,1,\sqrt{x}+1$

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}-1}=\sqrt{x}+1$

$$x=2$$

$\sqrt{2}-1,1,\sqrt{2}+1$...

Comment: You do not have the problem correct.  If we are not given $x$ the result must contain it.  Otherwise $x$ could be $2$ and $A=B=C=1$ would match the givens and the fifth term is also $1$  You can say $B^3=x-1$

Comment: I am sure the intended sequence has $B=1$ and ratio $1+\sqrt 2$, but I don't know how to justify that.  This just comes from the fact that $(1+\sqrt 2)^3=7+5\sqrt 2$

Comment: $B^3=x-1$ may help ?

Comment: The question needs to be improved, you cannot know the 5th term when you don't have enough information. What is $x$?

Comment: Okay, according to the answer of @Phil H, apparently $x$ was the ratio of the geometric sequence. Still, you need one more info to determine the sequence. Maybe $B=1$ is the missing part as suggested by Ross?

Comment: If $x$ is the ratio of the series my proposed series does not work because $ABC=1, x-1=\sqrt 2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $5$th term $E = 7 + 5\sqrt2$

Also, because $E^2 = DF$, then $DF = 99 + 70\sqrt2$

Roots that would fit $DF$ are $(3+2\sqrt2)(17+12\sqrt2) = 99+70\sqrt2$

This gives a ratio of $1 + \sqrt2$

Hence the sequence is $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt2},1, 1+\sqrt2, 3+2\sqrt2, 7 + 5\sqrt2, 17+12\sqrt2...\text{etc}$

Comment: This is a nice series that has the proper fifth term, but I don't see any justification for it.  It doesn't work if $x$ is the ratio of successive terms.

Comment: @Ross Millikan Where do you get that the ratio is x? Without specifying what x is, ABC = x - 1 poses no restrictions on a solution. I see what you are saying, and I have just shown a solution whereby the 5th term is $7 + 5\sqrt2$ but from the information given, there are an infinite number of solutions where the 5th term isn't that. I think the question is missing a piece of information, possibly that x = 2.

Comment: I was trying to rescue the problem and find a reason for the statement $ABC=x-1$, and a reason for expressing it as $x-1$ instead of $y$.